# Issue with subquery in same table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, subquery

I'm new in sql and I need help for this case using subquery.

I this case I need to grab all customerId under Amanda and UAmanda.But now I only have this customerId 100456.

How to I use this customerId 100456 combain subquery to get all data under Amanda and UAmanda.

Below is the table

| Customer_Id | Login_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 100456 | Amanda |
| 101287 | UAmanda |
| 102458 | Oliver |
| 103658 | Louis |

This is my subquery

```
select customer_id,login_name
from
(select tc.customer_id, tc.login_name from t_customers tc where tc.login_name = login_name)
where t_customers where customer_id = 100456;
```

but it only return me the Amanda with 100456 the others UAmanda did not return.

Can anyone help me on this issue?

This is the expected result I want

| Customer_Id | Login_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 100456 | Amanda |
| 101287 | UAmanda |

Comment: Please include the actual query you are using.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_id, login_name FROM t_customers WHERE login_name LIKE '%Amanda';
```

Comment: My answer works  I wanted to show usage of LIKE,  but the strict answer to your question is answer from @pcsutar that will not return xAmanda like mine ... your final choice depends on your real need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab all customerId under Amanda and UAmanda then I think there is no need of sub query. You can get the result using below query:

```
select customer_id, login_name
from t_customers
where login_name in ('Amanda', 'UAmanda');
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you say the only data you have is the `customer_Id` I believe you need the following:

```
select * 
from customers
where login_name like (
    select Concat('%',Login_Name,'%') 
    from customers
    where Customer_Id=100456
)
```